# cdc-acm driver: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem

Tags: wireless, usb-modem, modem

I am using **Beagleboard-xm** with **3.12 Kernel** and ubuntu rootfs from Robert Nelson's site.

I use a **Telit HE910 GPS+GSM** modem along with my project .So as per the HW user guide i have to apply a logic high for 5s on the input of this modem for enabling it

So when I does this by toggling the gpio pin for 5s using a script I'm getting some messages on the terminal

I am sure this message comes from the driver in `usb/class/cdc-acm.c` but couldn't find the reason behind this?

How can I solve this issue??

```
root@arm:~# ./modem_on.sh 
Turning on Telit modem ......
going to sleep and toggle
[   70.791381] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.390258] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.406890] cdc_acm 1-2:1.2: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.462188] cdc_acm 1-2:1.4: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.478363] cdc_acm 1-2:1.6: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.495269] cdc_acm 1-2:1.8: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.510040] cdc_acm 1-2:1.10: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.530090] cdc_acm 1-2:1.12: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.619720] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.634429] cdc_acm 1-2:1.2: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.649475] cdc_acm 1-2:1.4: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.664459] cdc_acm 1-2:1.6: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.678741] cdc_acm 1-2:1.8: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.693389] cdc_acm 1-2:1.10: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.708099] cdc_acm 1-2:1.12: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
Script complete ..........
```

The realted necessary portion of dmesg is below

```
[   30.623107] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   70.629943] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-omap
[   70.782501] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x81 has an invalid bInterval 255, changing to 11
[   70.782592] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=058b, idProduct=0041
[   70.782623] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[   70.791381] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   70.801483] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[   73.041625] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
[   74.209930] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-omap
[   74.369049] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1bc7, idProduct=0021
[   74.369110] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   74.369140] usb 1-2: Product: Telit Wireless Module
[   74.369171] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Telit wireless solutions
[   74.369201] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 357164042197668
[   74.390258] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.400207] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[   74.406890] cdc_acm 1-2:1.2: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.416900] cdc_acm 1-2:1.2: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[   74.462188] cdc_acm 1-2:1.4: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.472259] cdc_acm 1-2:1.4: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[   74.478363] cdc_acm 1-2:1.6: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.488372] cdc_acm 1-2:1.6: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
[   74.495269] cdc_acm 1-2:1.8: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.505279] cdc_acm 1-2:1.8: ttyACM4: USB ACM device
[   74.510040] cdc_acm 1-2:1.10: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.520141] cdc_acm 1-2:1.10: ttyACM5: USB ACM device
[   74.530090] cdc_acm 1-2:1.12: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.540283] cdc_acm 1-2:1.12: ttyACM6: USB ACM device
[   74.619720] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.629455] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[   74.634429] cdc_acm 1-2:1.2: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.644042] cdc_acm 1-2:1.2: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[   74.649475] cdc_acm 1-2:1.4: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.659027] cdc_acm 1-2:1.4: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[   74.664459] cdc_acm 1-2:1.6: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.674133] cdc_acm 1-2:1.6: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
[   74.678741] cdc_acm 1-2:1.8: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.688415] cdc_acm 1-2:1.8: ttyACM4: USB ACM device
[   74.693389] cdc_acm 1-2:1.10: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.703186] cdc_acm 1-2:1.10: ttyACM5: USB ACM device
[   74.708099] cdc_acm 1-2:1.12: This device cannot do calls on its own. It is not a modem.
[   74.717895] cdc_acm 1-2:1.12: ttyACM6: USB ACM device
```

`

Comment: Is this you device ? http://sell.lulusoso.com/selling-leads/1308738/HE910-embedded-linux.html if not look here and show which one it is http://www.telit.com/products/cellular/3g/

Comment: @markkirby kirby  YES teh first link shows my product. Any thoughts abuout the issue??

Comment: Embedded or PCI

Comment: Embedded . I am using beagleboard-xm with linux 3.12 kernel + ubuntu rootfs

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the driver directly

Open this file

```
/cdc-acm.c
```

I dont have it so you have to search from a shell or browser

Open it with this command

`sudo gedit /path/to/cdc-amc.c`

And change line 60 to

```
#include <linux/serial.h>
```

And line 613 to

```
set_bit(ASYNCB_INITIALIZED, &acm->port.flags);
```

You problem is very unique, this was the only patch I could find, for you error message and driver combination it was for USB driver version so I made small edits for you.

Please review my [source](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14103) and the [patch](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=23046&action=diff)

Comment: I couldn't find a sentence accoring to your patch on my source code